# Table and body design mismatch

Tags: html, css, jqgrid

I have following table structure

```
<table>
  <table>
   <thead>
    <tr>...header template...</tr>
   </thead>
  </table>
  <tbody>
   <tr> ... </tr>
   <tr> ... </tr>
   <tr> ... </tr>
  </tbody>
<table>
```

My problem is that the datarows and header rows are not aligned to each other.
The table structure looks wierd.

Any clue how can i make them aligned.

Edit:

I have used Jqgrid to populate my grid.
The table structure which jqgrid produces is like the above one.
If i dont wrap  within  tag, then the first  inside  disappears.
Somewhere i found that jquery.clean will clean up if we dont wrap  within table.

do u guys have any idea on this

Comment: Are you keeping the data inside <td> in <tr> tag?

Comment: Yes. in headerrows as well as in datarows

Comment: After first <table> you should use <tr> and <td> 's to wrap nested table also

Comment: If you use jqGrid and you have some problems with the usage of jqGrid you can append your question with screenshorts, the code and the test data which can be used to reproduce the problem. It would be good to create the demo which demonstrates the problem which you have. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) demo could be very good.

Answer (score 1):

You have so much syntax errors.
This is normal table:

```
<table border=1>

   <thead>
       <tr><th>header template</th></tr>
   </thead>

  <tbody>
      <tr><td>...</td></tr>
   <tr><td>...</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: `<thead>` should contain a `<tr>` and then a `<th>` (not `<td>`)

Answer (score 0):

Try using a syntax like this:

```
<table>
   <thead>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="2"> ...header template... </th>
    </tr>
   </thead>
  <tbody>
   <tr>
       <td> ... </td>
       <td> ... </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
       <td> ... </td>
       <td> ... </td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This is the same structure which i posted. Whats new.

Comment: @MARKANDBhatt no it's not. Look closely. The syntax errors are gone.

Comment: Where should the second table tag close?

Comment: @MARKANDBhatt the table should only be closed once. Sorry. See edit.

Comment: and you have syntax error again. in th you need to use `colspan` for  your structure

Answer (score 0):

A table have head and body and each can have rows and columns:

`<table>
   <thead>
    <tr><td></td></tr>
   </thead>
  <tbody>
   <tr><td></td></tr>
  </tbody>
<table>`

You can also see following [link](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_table.asp) for more details.

Cheers !!